# Adding ssh public key to root user on server

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I have been getting an error when trying to push to my remote Git repository and I think its because my root user on my server doesn't recognize me when I try to push to the remote repo. I am trying to add my ssh public to the root user on my server so I am able to push to a remote Git repository on the server. I have tried logging in as root and going to

```
/root/.ssh
```

and trying to add my public key from my local machine to the

```
known_hosts
```

file. I have noticed that the format is completely different in the

```
known_hosts
```

file compared to my ssh public key, is there a special way to add a public key to the known hosts file? Also I do not have an

```
authorized_keys
```

file in the

```
.ssh
```

directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: gemerally, it's considered as a bad idea to allow root user to access a host via ssh. Why do you need this?

Comment: @user3159253 I can't think of another reason why my remote Git repository is throwing an error saying -- fatal: 'live' does not appear to be a git repository, fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. -- when I try to push to it.

Comment: make sure, that 1. you can actually log in to the chosen account. 2. make sure that the chosen folder exists, and is actually a valid git repository, various git commands are successfully executed there. 3. make sure that you specifies the correct (full) path while accessing the repo from the outside. 4. bear in mind that root user is a special one, so accessing it via ssh may require additional configuration, mentioned above. that's it

Comment: "I have been getting an error when trying to push..." What specific command are you running, and what specific error are you getting?

Comment: @user3159253 I made the root user able to be accessed by SSH and then used the root user to access the remote repo and that seemed to have worked however I am still trying to figure out how to make the Git remote Git repo accessible by a regular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`known_hosts` is wrong. This is for saving identity of hosts you connect to from your server. 
`authorized_keys` is what you want. If you don't have it, create it. And make sure it has the right permissions set. I think it should be 600. Also make sure root is allowed to log in via SSH, this is often blocked by default, as it can be considered a security issue. After you have set up everything, make sure you can log in with your key via SSH and then try the push again if it worked. Also consider using another user but root.

Comment: Also I suggest you to use ssh-copy-id to copy public keys to the remote authorized_keys file. It avoids some of the common mistakes of modifying the authorized_keys by hand.